# in org capture the clipboard expansion (%x) does not work with daemon?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I have this org capture template saved in a `tpl-quote.txt` file:

```
* a title 
  :PROPERTIES:
  :TIME: %U
  :END:

%x  ;; contents in clipboard
```

And the `org-capture-templates` is

```
  (setq org-capture-templates
  (quote (("p" "Private Templates")
          ("pc" "Clipboard"
           entry
           (file+olp+datetree "~/Notebooks/org/default.org" "Capture")
           (file "~/Notebooks/org/tpl-quote.txt")
           :immediate-finish t))))
```

This worked alright in GUI Emacs.

If I start a GUI Emacs, run `M-x server-start`, then in a terminal run

```
emacsclient -ne '(org-capture nil "pc")'
```

it also worked Ok.

But if I start Emacs daemon `emacs --daemon`, then run the above `emacsclient` command I got the following error at my terminal:

```
*ERROR*: Capture abort: (wrong-type-argument char-or-string-p nil)
```

So it seems that the clipboard expansion %x is only working with GUI Emacs, deleting the %x it works again.

Is this the expected behavior?

My setup:

- OS: Manjaro Linux
- Emacs: 26.3
- Org-mode: 9.1.9

Comment: emacs --daemon calls server-start. What happens if you first open a frame (and close it) and then run your command line?

Comment: @RichieHH It gives the same error message. Could it be that something related to the X graphical things is not activated?

Comment: What happens when you leave the frame open and explicitly call this function inside the scratch buffer for example?

Comment: Also check with C-y (yank) in the scratch buffer.